# I need to compare between two function results but it always give me that they are equal

Tags: python

I need to compare between two functions outputs but it always printing that they are equal.
For example:

```
def test1():
    a =1
def test2():
    b = 2
test1()
test2()
if test1() != test2():
    print(‘test1 not equal to test2’)
else:
    print(‘test1 equal to test2’)
```

What is the problem here and how i can get the result that they not equal?
Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't appear as though your functions are returning anything to compare

Comment: You are comparing `None` to `None`, the default return value for functions that don't explicitly `return` anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to return the values you want to compare otherwise it's return value will always be None

```
def test1():
    a =1
    return a
def test2():
    b = 2
    return b
test1()
test2()
if test1() != test2():
    print("test1 not equal to test2")
else:
    print("test1 equal to test2")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the value.

```
def test1():
   return 1
def test2():
   return 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Each of your functions assigns to a local variable (which is immediately released when the function finishes), then returns nothing. When a Python lacks a `return` statement (or the `return` is empty, with no associated value to return), the implicit return value is `None`. Since neither has a `return <insert useful thing here>` statement, both functions return `None`, and their results are equal. If you want them to return different things, change them to `return` a useful value:

```
def test1():
    return 1
def test2():
    return 2
```